# How to get Updated Consumer price index (CPI) from a website in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath

Need to get [India's CPI](https://in.investing.com/economic-calendar/indian-cpi-973) and update all the prices in my sheet every year based on it.

I tried using IMPORTXML (“url”,”xpath”), but that doesn’t seem to work, i am getting "N/A" error.

I used this "xpath" : /html/body/div/div[4]/section[1]/div/header/div/div[2]/dl[1]/div[1]

What i essentially want is for the function to pull the actual(CPI) from the website and adjust the prices in my sheet.

Am i using the wrong function ? or am i wrong in my application of the funciton ?